# Can you make trigger exceptions pretty in standard page layouts?

Tags: trigger, exception, error-messages

We have a situation where it is possible for a trigger to throw an exception that will be shown to the end user.

This isn't ideal as the user sees a lengthy message containing what is essentially a stack trace.

Is there a clean way for a trigger to raise an error to be shown to the user in a standard page layout without the stack trace kind of output?

E.g. similar to the ApexPages.Message in controllers

*I've included a screenshot of an example message - the message content isn't important, it's the "Apex trigger ContactTrigger caused an unexpected exception...", etc that you should focus on.*

[image: Example Message Format]

---

As an expansion of the answer given below:

```
try {
  // thing that throws an exception
}
catch ( Exception e ) {
  theSObjectYouAreManipulating.addError( 'This is the error you show to the user!' );
}
```

This results in a much more standard and clean error message.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you considered adding try/catch logic around any code that might cause an exception and then using the addError() method to display a more friendly error message to the user?